# replace NA with 0 and all other values/text as 1

Tags: r

```
airquality

    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1      41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2      36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3      12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4      18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5      NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6      28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
7      23     299  8.6   65     5   7
8      19      99 13.8   59     5   8
9       8      19 20.1   61     5   9
```

Hi there,

How do I replace values in Ozone to be binary?  If NA then 0 and if a value then 1.

Thanks
H

Comment: `as.integer(is.na(df$Ozone))`

Comment: @Sotos `!is.na(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is called `airquality`

```
airquality$Ozone <- ifelse(is.na(airquality$Ozone), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
airquality$Ozone <- as.integer(!is.na(airquality$Ozone))
```

Comment: I think `as.integer` is a bit more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

```
airquality$Ozone[!is.na(airquality$Ozone)] <- 1L
airquality$Ozone[is.na(airquality$Ozone)] <- 0L
```